# How do I interface with bundles using ESRI's Javascript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tilecache

I've found this example... http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/layers_custom_tiled.html

Which uses an exploded cache. It notes at the beginning of the article...

"You would most likely use ArcGISTileMapServiceLayer when accessing a service from 9.3 and beyond"

Digging into the ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer object it seems like it only connects to services via the rest url. I need to accomplish what is achieved in the Portland example (the link above) but with cache bundles instead of the exploded cache.

**Potentially Useful Background**: I need to make an entirely self contained web map app with the javascript api that would use bundles that are stored with the app (as opposed to out on a server with arcgis installed) to render the map.

Comment: How do you plan to access the tiles? Still over http?

Comment: Any way possible? If I could just access them through the relative file structure that'd be nice.

Comment: It's gotta be entirely locally contained ultimately, but I'm just trying to take baby steps at this point.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link to a jsfiddle showing a custom non-ArcGIS tiled map service. Regarding being entirely locally contained, what kind of device will this run on? If it's a laptop, you're good...if you're talking phone or tablet, I think local storage if your best bet(but then you're pretty limited on the amount of data your  app can use).

Comment: @Carter, I don't think its possible todo what you are seeking; AGS is what provides the way to get to the bundled images; unless you have a exploded cache you don't be able to get to the content of the bundle. The assumption of all the sources you see is that you are using AGS to host/serve the cache. You can access exploded cache directly and offline but you are seeking for bundles and that isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks D.E Wright. That was my hunch.

@Derek, cool example, thanks for writing that up! I will ultimately be used on a laptop or desktop without access to any of our services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can find and what D.E. Wright mention in the comments above, I've concluded that it's not possible to access the bundle files via the JS API.

I wound up just creating an exploded cache to use in this instance and it's worked fine.

**Note:** Although I've marked my own answer to this question as THE answer (because I believe it is the answer the my original question), I want to draw attention to Derek Swingley's answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

I think there are two things that should help you accomplish this:

- [documentation for creating custom layers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp/inside_custom_layers.htm)
- [sample showing how to
  put tiles in local storage](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/exp_webstorage.html)

Side note:  you linked to the 1.6 docs. While valid for 1.6, [the current version of the API is 2.5](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm) and we recommend you use that as 1.6 is no longer being updated.

**Edit:** Here's a working example of a custom layer using tiles non-ArcGIS Server endpoints:  http://jsfiddle.net/swingley/V5DcN/4/

Besides the base map, the tiles are coming from [rootmetrics.com](http://rootmetrics.com/).

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I wound up on the 1.6 documentation.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm not sure it is what I'm looking for. The first article is actually the one I had been working off, but it's most pertinent example (the custom tiled layer type one) basically ties into the exploded tiles. Whereas I have bundles. The second article still seems to need to connect via the ArcGIS rest stuff. Perhaps my question needs to be reworded.